# Get the value of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I was using wit.ai's JSON to get the data and recently they changed the structure. This is how it looks

```
"entities": {
  "paraName:paraName": [
     {
        "id": "1266de86-97af-434b-95ee-f87ff58c935a",
        "name": "paraName",
        "role": "paraName",
        "start": 30,
        "end": 34,
        "body": "data",
        "confidence": 0.549,
        "entities": [

        ],
        "suggested": true,
        "value": "data",
        "type": "value"
     },
     {
        "id": "1266de86-97af-434b-95ee-f87ff58c935a",
        "name": "paraName",
        "role": "paraName",
        "start": 39,
        "end": 45,
        "body": "height",
        "confidence": 0.8922,
        "entities": [

        ],
        "value": "height",
        "type": "value"
     }
  ]
```

}

This is how I am trying to get the value of those parameters (i.e. data, and height)

```
    let data = response.entities;
    let paraMeter = data.paraName.map(function(res){
        return res['value'];
    })
    keyValues = paraMeter.join().split(',');
```

but I am getting Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error. Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: What `data.paraName` shows in console, probably should be `data["paraName:paraName"].map(.....`?

Comment: That Json is not valid line 2 `"paraName:paraName": [`
Check out this tool https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Typo. The property is `"paraName:paraName"` not `"paraName"`.

Comment: @MosheSommers — The only thing invalid about the JSON is that the `{` at the start was left out when it was transcribed. Colons are allowed in property names.

Comment: @Mamun it shows undefined.  is how the api is display now the data 
https://wit.ai/docs/http/20200513#get__message_link

Comment: @Quentin You're right sorry about that

Comment: @MosheSommers, it is a valid JSON

Comment: "paraName:paraName" is the first key so what you need is: 

data["paraName:paraName"] which will return an array that you can iterate over.

Comment: @Jack, that's it Mate. Thank you very much

Comment: Cool@BinitaGyawali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the key like shown in this snippet:

> `let paraMeter = data["paraName:paraName"].map(function(ref){`

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) :

> Properties of JavaScript objects can also be accessed or set using a
>   bracket notation (for more details see property accessors). Objects
>   are sometimes called associative arrays, since each property is
>   associated with a string value that can be used to access it.

```js
let response = {"entities": {
  "paraName:paraName": [
     {
        "id": "1266de86-97af-434b-95ee-f87ff58c935a",
        "name": "paraName",
        "role": "paraName",
        "start": 30,
        "end": 34,
        "body": "data",
        "confidence": 0.549,
        "entities": [

        ],
        "suggested": true,
        "value": "data",
        "type": "value"
     },
     {
        "id": "1266de86-97af-434b-95ee-f87ff58c935a",
        "name": "paraName",
        "role": "paraName",
        "start": 39,
        "end": 45,
        "body": "height",
        "confidence": 0.8922,
        "entities": [

        ],
        "value": "height",
        "type": "value"
     }
  ]}
  };
  
  let data = response.entities;
    let paraMeter = data["paraName:paraName"].map(function(ref){
        return ref['value'];
    })
    keyValues = paraMeter.join().split(',');
    console.log(keyValues);
```

Comment: This is how the data is displaying in JSON "paraName:paraName": [

Comment: correct - it is a valid json key - i have updated the answer accordingly